# Need To Align Text With Images Inside Divs

Tags: html, image, alignment

I am trying to align a header and a paragraph with the images on the page but I'm having difficulty doing so. I want two rows, each with a pictures and the things I listed above.

This is the format I want, but I can't seem to get the text that I have along side the pictures. Here is the code:

```css
h5 {
 font-family:'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size:26px;
 color:#00ffff;
}
p.par {
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#030303;
}
.sample {
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
 
}
#bodywrap {
 width:1400px;
 margin:0 auto;
 clear:both;
}
#firstrow, #secondrow {
 width:600px;
 float:left;
 margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodywrap">
  <div id="firstrow">
    <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample1" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
    <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample2" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="secondrow">
    <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample3" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
    <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample4" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with align? Do you want the text and pictures have the same width? Or you would like the text stay on the right of each picture, aligned top?

Comment: Use any paint app and draw your desire requirement so we can understand your design properly.

Comment: Correct, I want the text on the right and to the top next to the photos. I tried uploading a picture and it told me I did not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap each content section in a container (you'll have more control down the road if you choose to adjust things) and float your `a` tags (since they wrap your image) to the left:

**HTML**

```
<div id="bodywrap">
  <div id="firstrow">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample1" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"/></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample2" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"/></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
      </div>
      </div>
  <div id="secondrow">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample3" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"/></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
      </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="gallery.html"><img src="sample4" alt="Go To Gallery" class="sample"/></a>
    <h5>Pictures</h5>
    <p class="par">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    </p>
      </div>
      </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h5 {
   font-family:'Muli', sans-serif;
   font-size:26px;
   color:#00ffff;
   padding: 0; //clear default
   margin: 0; //clear default
}

.wrapper{ 
   overflow: hidden; //clears the float
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 15px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/arxdpy2z/)